# Django admin is very slow when loading from the OneToOne user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

I think I am doing admin model wrong because it is taking like 30 seconds to load and I think its because my sql queries are too inefficient and there may be creating more look ups than needed. Is there a way that I can speed this up?

````py
class UserInformationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'user_username',
        'user_first_name',
        'user_last_name',
        'major'
    )

    @admin.display(description='user.username')
    def user_username(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.user.username
        except Exception:
            return None

    @admin.display(description='user.first_name')
    def user_first_name(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.user.first_name
        except Exception:
            return None

    @admin.display(description='user.last_name')
    def user_last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.last_name```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can understand having

```
    list_select_related = True
```

convert the queries to a `select_related` queries, which are much faster. Here was the ultimate code that essentially worked.

````py
class UserInformationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_select_related = True
    
    list_display = (
        'user_username',
        'user_first_name',
        'user_last_name',
        'major'
    )

    @admin.display(description='user.username')
    def user_username(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.user.username
        except Exception:
            return None

    @admin.display(description='user.first_name')
    def user_first_name(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.user.first_name
        except Exception:
            return None

    @admin.display(description='user.last_name')
    def user_last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.last_name```
````

Comment: I have same problem, but this solution doesn't solve it :(